# How to program a simple weather check app?

Tags: weather-api, feed

I'm pretty new to programming (I've only learned basic Java and Python), but I'm really interested in application development. So, I wanted to create a simple app that checks the chance for rain from a specific weather site. If the chance of rain is greater than or equal to 50%, it simply displays "Carry an umbrella". If chance is less than 50%, say "Don't need an umbrella".

I tried to read some other questions about creating a weather app on this site and they talked about using APIs, but besides me doing a little research on what an API is, I have no idea what's going on. And, I don't want to make it complicated.

Also, I'm aware that there's already some apps that do this (such as one from Yahoo). However, I'm not just looking for a prebuilt app. My goal is to learn a little bit more about app development by creating simple app that will retrieve information from a site, and display it to me. I don't care very much about the weather aspect, but it seemed like a simple example to give.

I'm just looking for guidance on how to go about doing this, so if someone can explain how, or provide any useful links, that'd be great! Thanks!

Edit: Oh also, I am looking to build on Windows (not Android or iOS).